# Leave snippet shortcut VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts, code-snippets

Is there a shortcut in Visual Studio 2010, while entering VB code, to leave snippet? In this case I have to press bottom arrow few times to leave the Property snippet.

[image: Property snippet]

Comment: Similar to question [How to complete a Visual Studio snippet in VB.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4831160/70716)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to insert a snippet (by default)
- <kbd>TAB</kbd> to navigate and edit
- <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to leave